# How to properly Initialize vector<int> & vecRef? Throwing error C2758

Tags: c++, vector

I have run into this situation where I need to constantly pass a vector around.  The ideal idea is to pass it by reference so the program doesn't slow down from constantly copying the vector.

class Bar has the original vector.

Bar.h:

```
#ifndef Bar_h
#define Bar_h

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Bar{

public:

    Bar();
    vector<int> & getVec();

private:
    vector<int> vec;
};
#endif
```

Bar.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Bar.h"

using namespace std;

Bar::Bar(){
    vec.push_back(1);
    vec.push_back(2);
    vec.push_back(3);
    vec.push_back(4);
    vec.push_back(5);
}

vector<int> & Bar::getVec(){
    return vec;
}
```

Class foo receives the vector.

foo.h:

```
#ifndef Foo_h
#define Foo_h

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Foo{

public:

    Foo();

private:
    vector<int> & vecRef;
};
#endif
```

foo.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Foo.h"
#include "Bar.h"

using namespace std;

Foo::Foo(){

    Bar bar;



    vecRef = bar.getVec();
}
```

main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Foo.h"

using namespace std;

void main(){

    Foo foo();

}
```

The problem is that when compiling I get Error code C2758 which stats "a member of reference type must be initialized".  It is referring to the foo class and vector<'int> & vecRef; not being initialized properly.  My question is how would I go about properly initializing vecRef while keeping its declaration in foo.h?  (i have done it successfully by declaring vecRef in foo.cpp, but that's not what i want if possible).  OR is adding the '&' into vector<'int> & vecRef; not the way to go about this at all?

Comment: `Foo();` constructor must initialize the reference `vecRef` in a member initializer list. It's not possible without `Bar` passed as a constructor parameter or being a member variable of `Foo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

References must be initialized in the member initializer list here:

```
Foo::Foo()
: vecRef(???) // <==
{ }
```

If a member variable isn't listed there, it will be default-initialized, and a reference cannot be default-initialized - hence the error. Furthermore, it's a good thing your code doesn't compile, because otherwise:

```
{
    Bar bar;
    vecRef = bar.getVec();
} // <== bar gets destroyed here
  // vecRef is now a dangling reference
```

What you likely want to do is pass a `Bar` into `Foo`'s constructor, by reference, and then initialize `vecRef` like so:

```
Foo::Foo(Bar& bar)
: vecRef(bar.getVec())
{ }
```

Or just take the reference directly:

```
Foo::Foo(std::vector<int>& v)
: vecRef(v)
{ }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I wasn't able to get your first suggestion working for what ever reason (I'm new to C++) but the 2nd one worked fine.  Ill try to incorporate this method into my real program now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A reference cannot reference nothing. Thus you have to initialize `foo`s `vecRef` in the constructor. Actually this is explained already in detail in Barrys answer and I just wanted to point out the following:

Once you provide public access to a reference of a member variable, there is no point in making this member variable private. You could as well make `vec` itself public in `Bar` (and not need a getter method). It would have the same effect but with less superfluous typing needed from you.